# File Upload Exception

Tags: jsp, file-upload, apache-commons-fileupload

I tried to use the file upload using Apache Commons but the following exception thrown

the request doesn't contain a `multipart/form-data` or `multipart/mixed stream`, `content type` header is `null`

**html code**

```
Form method="post" action="getData.jsp" enctype="multipart/form-data"    
input type="file" name="upload"
```

**JSP code**

```
 DiskFileUpload upload = new DiskFileUpload();         
 boolean isMultipart=upload.isMultipartContent(request);   


List items = upload.parseRequest(request); //this line throw exception.
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Post the stacktrace of your exception , **P.S Pls dont use jsp for file-upload servlets are meant for that purpose**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet?rq=1